# Getting the session values from the browser in test case writing protractor spec.js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, protractor-net

I've tried:

```
browser.executeScript("return window.sessionStorage.getItem('UserDataSession');");
```

---

```
browser.driver.executeScript('sessionStorage.getItem("UserDataSession");');
```

---

```
browser.sleep(2000);
browser.driver.executeScript('sessionStorage.getItem("UserDataSession");')
  .then(function(retValue) {

  });
```

but neither are working for me.

I am trying use these codes in protractor e2e testing for angularjs spec.js file.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Are you resolving the promise that the executeScript returns? Here's how - `browser.executeScript("return window.sessionStorage.getItem('UserDataSession');").then(function(sess){console.log(sess);})`.

Comment: when i use the above code i got an error--------
" SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: okey fine,now i got the result....THANK YOU

Comment: Updated it as answer. If its right then please mark it as answer so that it helps others. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be taking the promise that `executeScript()` returns and then use it to do your actions. Here's how -

```
browser.executeScript("return window.sessionStorage.getItem('UserDataSession');")
.then(function(sess){
    console.‌​log(sess);
});
```

Hope this helps.